# Angular ui-select : Adding custom ids

Tags: ui-select

I am using angular ui-select.

```
<ui-select  ng-model="selected" theme="select2">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select">{{$select.selected.name}}
    </ui-select-match>   
    <ui-select-choices 
         repeat="student in studentList | filter: $select.search"
         ng-class="{{student.name}}  == 'ABC' ? 'found' : 'not_Found' ">
         {{student.name}}          
    </ui-select-choices>   
</ui-select>
```

Can we add custom ids to each of the new li formed from the ui-select-choices?
If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the ugly but standard Angular repeat syntax:

```
repeat="student.id as student in studentList | ..."
```